# Es RESTful, ¿Es una buena practica insertar varios elementos en una solicitud?

Tags: json, rest

Me surgió una gran duda de si es una buena practica **insertar un lote de elementos en una sola solicitud** en RESTful, ó iterarlos e **insertar un elemento por solicitud**, tengo esa duda ya que en mi aplicacion frontend, el usuario va acumulando objetos y una vez terminado los insertaria de la siguiente manera:

POST /objetos

```
[
 {
  "name": "objeto1"
 },
 {
  "name": "objeto2"
 }
]
```

Lo que no me queda claro aun es que debo hacer procesarlos en una sola solicitud o iteralos y enviarlos uno por uno
si me pudieran orientar
Gracias

Comment: Bulk insert es muy valido en las apis, de hecho hay pantallas donde se tienen colecciones de datos y es necesario procesar todo, ejemplo en un punto de venta, cuando llenas el carrito y procesas la venta se tiene que enviar toda la información y procesarse en una sola transacción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cuanto a si enviar todo en una misma solicitud, sí, no habría problema. Ya depende de lo que quieras conseguir, por rendimiento o transaccionalidad, o de cómo esté implementado el cliente-servidor, podrías hacerlo de una manera u otra.

Para enviarlos-recibirlos, simplemente trabaja con una `List<TuDTO>` (suponiendo Java, aplicable al lenguaje que uses).

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu respuesta es más bien un comentario, que una respuesta propiamente dicha, ya que las mismas deben de intentar no recabar información del usuario que realiza la pregunta. No se deben de basar en opiniones. Para eso el sitio, tiene los comentarios. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Comment: @Javifer2 bueno, en realidad la pregunta original tampoco se presta a una "respuesta propiamente dicha". Esta respuesta la veo bien, partiendo de lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2, en este caso no me queda claro qué tipo de respuesta sería más apropiada basada en la pregunta, como dice ArianJM. Un saludo.